# Hook for When an Existing Nodes Group Audience is Change

Tags: organic-groups

I would like to be able to respond to content being added to an organic group. Specifically I would like to know when a node's group audience entity reference has been changed to add (or remove) that content to a group.

I can't seem to find a hook that will let me identify when this happens. Could someone help me and point me in the right direction.